# How to run Flask app as a package in PyCharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I was following [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/#simple-packages) documentation on directory management for Flask projects. Now, I'm trying to run my flask application from PyCharm. I have added the below mentioned Environment Variables in `Edit Configurations...`:

`FLASK_DEBUG=true`

`FLASK_APP=<absolute-path-to-root-directory-of-application>`

I add the `Script` as `flask run`

[image]

The output running this configuration is this:

> ../red-flask/venv/bin/python "flask run"
>
> ../red-flask/venv/bin/python: can't open file 'flask run': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>
> Process finished with exit code 2

My project directory looks like:

```
/flask_app
    setup.py
    /flask_app
        __init__.py
        views.py
        /static
            style.css
        /templates
            layout.html
            index.html
            login.html
            ...
```

I am unable to figure out how to make this work, any help is appreciated.

Comment: your script is not named 'flask run'. You either need `flask run` by itself without the interpreter invocation in front or `python -m flask run`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is documented in the development build of the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/#pycharm-integration).

You need to point to the location of the `flask` command.

- Script: `/path/to/env/bin/flask`
- Script parameters: `run`

Until 1.0 comes out, you need to point `FLASK_APP` at `__init__.py` if you don't install your package in your env.

- Environment variables: `FLASK_APP` `/path/to/flask_app/__init__.py`

Preferably, install the package in the env and point to it using the import name.

- From the terminal, in the virtualenv: `pip install -e .`
- Environment variables: `FLASK_APP` `flask_app`